# Create a localized string with a generated comment

Tags: swift, string, localization, literals, ios16

My framework contains a protocol that allows conforming types to describe themselves. One of its requirements is a static member containing the name of the type. This can be used as (for example) the header of a `SwiftUI.List` displaying a list of conforming types.

```
public protocol Describable: Identifiable {
    static var className: LocalizedStringResource { get }

    // ...
}

struct ItemList<I: Describable>: View {
    let items: [I]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(I.className)
            .font(.title)
        List(items) { item in
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The above works fine, but I want to be able to annotate the key with a comment, and to be able to vary the key by plurality, so that a `struct Building { ... }` can have a localized key for the plural 'Buildings' (and equivalent plural forms in other languages).

Optimally, the protocol should provide this functionality automatically to conforming types, however I don't know how to achieve this properly with `LocalizedStringResource` and the new string catalog (Localizable.xcstrings). The keys being added to my project contain a second variable instead of the class name (e.g. `%1$lld %2$@`). Below are some of my attempts:

```
public protocol Describable: Identifiable {
    static var localizedClassName: LocalizedStringResource { get }
    static var className: String { get }
    static var staticClassName: StaticString { get }
    // ...
}

extension Describable {
    
    static func classDescription(for count: Int) -> LocalizedStringResource {
        "\(count) \(className)"
    }
    
    static func classDescription2(for count: Int) -> LocalizedStringResource {
        "\(count) \(staticClassName.asString)"
    }
    
    static func classDescription3(for count: Int) -> LocalizedStringResource {
        LocalizedStringResource("\(count) \(staticClassName.asString)", comment: "Type Description")
    }
}

private extension StaticString {
    var asString: String {
        self.withUTF8Buffer { String(decoding: $0, as: UTF8.self) }
    }
}
```

I've tried a few more variations, but the mixed usage of `LocalizedStringResource`, `StaticString`, `String`, `String.LocalizationValue` and other string literals makes my brain hurt and none of it looks correct anymore. What is the proper way to do this? Or am I trying to reinvent the wheel and does such functionality already exist within Swift?

Comment: You do indeed seem to be reinventing the wheel. String catalogs have pluralisation built-in. Just edit the string catalog. You don't need to change your `Describable` protocol at all.

Comment: For comments that's true I suppose, although if a project has many conforming types, I would've liked to be able to comment those automatically. However the 'vary by plural' option is disabled for the keys that are added.

Comment: For "vary by plural" to be enabled, you need a `%lld` or similar placeholder in the key. So you will need to add an extra key, in addition to just the word itself.

Comment: I realized my code didn't really show anything regarding plurality so I've edited it for clarity.